# Bootstrap DatePicker subtract days

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

Below is my snippet code. I want to set the default value of my calendar from date today subtracted to 7 days. Below code is not working since its sets the current date, See my screenshot.

```
$( "datepast" ).datepicker
    (
        {
            rtl: Metronic.isRTL(),
            language: 'neo',
            orientation: "center",
            autoclose: true,
            date: $( gSelector + "_past_val" ).val(),
            beforeShowDay: function( dt ) { return dt <= new Date(); }
        }
    )
    .datepicker("setDate", "-7") );
```

**Output of above code:**

[image]

Comment: Or simply change `.datepicker("setDate", "-7") );` to `.datepicker("setDate", "-7d") );`

Comment: @Pedram I subtracted the current month to 1 which is working with this code .datepicker("setDate", "-1m"). But I want also to set the day to always 1st day. how would I do that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `startDate` to enable previous 7 days compared to current date.

```
var todayDate = new Date();
todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 7);
$( "datepast" ).datepicker
(
    {
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        startDate: '-7d',
        setDate: 'today'
    }
).datepicker("setDate", todayDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `date` object, and subtract it, use `setDate` to set new value.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);

$('.datepast').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
    return dt <= new Date();
  }
}).datepicker("setDate", d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-bqVeqGdJ7h/lYPq6xrPv/YGzMEb6dNxlfiTUHSgRCp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-siyOpF/pBWUPgIcQi17TLBkjvNgNQArcmwJB8YvkAgg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<input class="datepast" />
```

**Update:**

Or simply change

```
.datepicker("setDate", "-7") )
```

**to**

```
.datepicker("setDate", "-7d") )
```

Comment: But It will not set the value in the calendar itself, what I mean is that it should turn the date to color blue, like its already selected.

Comment: @user3012377 not understand correctly, it's already selected 6 feb, as selected, what's the problem?

Comment: @user3012377 good, glad to help if my answer solved, you can accept it. good luck

Comment: I subtracted the current month to 1 which is working with this code .datepicker("setDate", "-1m"). But I want also to set the day to always 1st day. how would I do that? thanks

Comment: @user3012377 this is new question *!*

Comment: I cant post a question anymore, I need to wait days more to post again.

Comment: @user3012377 okay I'll check this out!